# Drinking whey protein twice a day

Tags: protein, protein-shakes, post-workout, whey

I am 29 years old and started working out 2-3 months ago, hitting the gym 4-5 days a week in the morning.

I take half scoop whey 30-45 mins before a workout and 1 scoop after a 1 1/2 hr intense workout, intend to gain weight.

Is it good to take whey protein within a short time?

Comment: Whey has no magical powers, it's regular food, just a bit more disgusting. What else do you eat? Only your entire diet will determine if you lose or gain weight

Comment: But It whould be more help full if you take any energy drink before workout